# PUT http request query

Tags: networking, http-headers, tcp, arduino-uno

Actually I am trying to send PUT request to a remote server the request is successfully send to the remote server but unfortunately the request is considered a bad request it can not see the body of the request I hope my discription is clear and here is the code for sending the request in Arduino programming language:

```
 Serial.println("Sending to Server: ");   
client.print("PUT /***/***/sensor/uod/1/A/1 HTTP/1.1\n");
Serial.print("PUT /***/***/sensor/uod/1/A/1 HTTP/1.1");                                       
client.print("Host: ********.koding.io\n");
client.print("Cache-Control: no-cache\n");
client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n");
client.print("status=1");
```

one thing I want to mention that from the server side I used a tool that is called postman and from it it works successfully without any error and actually I have taken it's http request and convert it into the code to be send and you can find the http request below:

```
 PUT /***/***/sensor/uod/1/A/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: *******.koding.io
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8740ccb4-c0f2-a916-fd52-3089e4f3cbc9
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

status=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve the problem by adding content-Length: 10 header

```
Serial.println("Sending to Server: ");   
client.print("PUT /***/***/sensor/uod/1/A/1 HTTP/1.1\n");
Serial.print("PUT /***/***/sensor/uod/1/A/1 HTTP/1.1");                                       
client.print("Host: *********.koding.io\n");
client.print("Cache-Control: no-cache\n");
client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
client.print("Content-Length: 10\r\n\r\n");
client.print("status=1\r\n");
```